# Im using CMYK/8 but my prints are still dull why is this? (Not RGB to CMYK issue)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, print-design, print-production

I've created my artwork for wedding invites in Photoshop (CMYK/8), placed them in an InDesign doc and when I print the colours, they are coming out exceptionally dull to the point the colours look faded. Could this be an issue with the printer? Or are my colour profiles incorrect?

Comment: Hi, welcome to GDSE. Is this for a home/office inkjet printer?  If so, these consumer grade printers generally can't print CMYK images. They're set up to expect RGB images.

Comment: Can you describe the process? In what mode the PDS is in? Do you print straight form indesing or you make a pdf? If the second with what profile? What is the printer you print it on? Is it calibrated?

Comment: For information only: Colors printed by a print machine which uses CMYK inks do not  become bright and punchy as soon as one creates his work in Photoshop or InDesign  by using CMYK mode instead of RGB. The available color range of the printing process is still the same. The colors can look bright and punchy if they are selected properly and there's nothing really colorful visible in the same time.

Comment: "when I print the colours, they are coming out exceptionally dull" is this your own desktop printer, or is this output from a commercial source using commercial equipment?